Handle Checkpoint timeouts in Apache Flink Long Running Event
We have an application where we have a set of rules and members. Whenever a new rule comes as an event, we need to run this rule across all the members present. There are millions of members and this is stored in the Keyed state.
This event takes hours to process and works when checkpoints are not enabled. When checkpoints are enabled it's getting timed out after 10 mins.
One of the solutions I was thinking of was to split the job into two.

The first job will take the rule event. Form a Tuple<Rule, Member> and publish it to an intermediate Kafka. This job replicates the rule event for each of the members.

In the second job, the actual rule processing will happen.


Is there a better way to handle this scenario?
Edit
Following are the steps that I am doing in the current job.
memberStream.keyBy("key is membership number")
  .connect(ruleStream.broadcast())
  .process(
    // This operator stores the member state when member event comes
    // When rule event comes it forms a Tuple<Rule, Member> for each of the members in the state and forward it to the next operator
  )
  .flatMap(
    // does the rule processing
  )
  .addSink(
    // Write to DB
  );


The reason why the job is failing is that a checkpoint is timing out, which is happening because the operator with the keyed state is running for hours in response to a single event. This prevents the checkpoint barrier from triggering the checkpoint in that operator, and then continuing downstream.
You've proposed having the operator with the keyed state emit a Tuple<Rule, Member> for each affected Member, and sending those tuples to an another job  (via Kafka). An alternative would be to put that rule processing logic in the original job, but in an operator downstream of the operator holding all of the keyed state. Go ahead and emit the tuples, as proposed, but process them in the original job. You'll also need to  enable unaligned checkpointing, so that the checkpoints can complete before timing out.
One potential problem with this alternative is that the checkpoints taken during rule processing will become larger, but if there will only be millions of these tuples, that shouldn't be too painful.
(Another approach would be to put a flatmap in front of the operator with all of the keyed member state that expands each new rule into 100 new rules, each affecting only 1% of the members. Same basic idea, just turning it around.)

I have already enabled unaligned checkpoints and rule processing is in the next operator to the Keyed state, still getting timed out.
Can Flink take checkpoints event when an event is being processed, or does it have to wait for the event to complete processing?

Flink cannot take a checkpoint in an operator while that operator is doing event processing.

Does that mean that when a rule event comes, Flink cannot take checkpoints until it's processed fully?

Yes. The synchronous part of checkpointing is done in the same thread that runs user functions. A single invocation of a user function will not be interrupted to deal with checkpointing -- the function will first run to completion, and only then will the checkpoint be drawn (if the checkpoint barrier is the next event). Unaligned checkpointing allows the barrier to skip ahead to the front of the input queue, but it still has to wait for the previous event to be processed.

This is essential for achieving exactly once semantics: every event that has begun being processed must have its full effect on both the state and output of that operator before the snapshot of that operator can be taken.

As you have proposed if the rule processing and the state of the members are in the same job, Flink will have to wait for the event completion to take checkpoints. In that case, wouldn't the checkpoint timeout as the rule event take hours to process?

I'm suggesting you might be able to break up in the monolithic rule event processing into a series of small steps, each applying the new rule to the state for one key at a time.

I have done a keyBy for the member events. I am not sure of a way to do a keyBy for the rule event.
I have edited the question to include more details about the current job.

I have tried running the job using a discarding sink and even in that case I am getting a checkpoint timeout. Is that because I am not allotting enough resources for the job or am I doing something wrong here?
Also, how much RAM and CPU should be allocated for jobs like these?
You mentioned breaking up the monolithic rule event processing into a series of small steps, can you please elaborate on that?

Each operator is single threaded, and checkpointing is done synchronously with respect to event processing. So checkpointing is blocked while an operator is handling an event. If processing a single event takes too long, checkpointing will timeout. So you need to find a way to do less work for each event, probably by making the events more granular.
